# PySpark cogroup on multiple keys

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given two lists, I want to group them based on the co-occurence of the first two keys:

```
x=[(1,(2,'cat')),(4,(5,'dog'))]
y=[(1,(2,'hairBall')),(4,(5,'woof'))]
```

desired output:

```
z=[(1,2,('cat','hairBall')),(4,5,('dog','woof'))]
```

what I have tried so far:

```
sc=SparkContext()
xs=sc.parallelize(x)
ys=sc.parallelize(y)

zs_temp=xs.cogroup(ys)
```

this results in:

```
zs_temp.collect()=[(1, [[(2, 'cat')], [(2, 'hairBall')]]), (4, [[(5, 'dog')], [(5, 'woof')]])]
```

attempted solution:

```
zs_temp.map(lambda f: f[1].cogroup(f[1]) ).collect()
```

but get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'cogroup'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test Data:

```
x=[(1,(2,'cat')),(4,(5,'dog'))]
y=[(1,(2,'hairBall')),(4,(5,'woof'))]
xs=sc.parallelize(x)
ys=sc.parallelize(y)
```

Function to change the keys

```
def reKey(r):
    return ((r[0], r[1][0]), r[1][1])
```

Change keys

```
xs2 = xs.map(reKey)
ys2 = ys.map(reKey)
```

Join Data, collect results

```
results = ys2.join(xs2)
results.collect()
```

> [((1, 2), ('hairBall', 'cat')), ((4, 5), ('woof', 'dog'))]